# PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

I am trying to learn about [kartik-v/yii2-grid](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid).

I use PHP 7.4 and configured it correctly to display a grid view table with panel property on it.

I tried all the export options such as HTML, CSV, Text, Excel, and JSON and it worked for me.

But when I tried to export as PDF, I encountered this error

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: `$psName` is a string, `count()` is for arrays. Use `strlen()` to get the length of a string.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: That's just a warning Yii has turned into an error exception for your convenience. Consult the PHP manual for your language reference.

Comment: Don't learn with PHP 7.4, it is already outdated. Use current PHP 8.2 instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering, may you remove your down vote on me. I am very new in this. I needed votes. please help me. Thanks

Comment: I already removed the image I uploaded. Thanks again.

Comment: Well asked questions get upvotes, bad ones get downvotes. To improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I will do so, thank you very much

Comment: @RamonGumban: In which file/line is that warning given and what is the code (show with +/- 3 lines around)? And thanks for [edit]ing the question.